# Best ways learn basic web security

Tags: php, mysql, security, ssl

I'm 16 and do a lot of web design for people. I do mostly front end design apart from the occasional bit of PHP when handling forms. While I do know how to manage basic sterilisation and validation, i would like to learn more intricate things like user management and login systems. I know my way around js, MySQL and PHP, etc... but I don't feel confident securing such systems. I know there is not one solve all guide to web security, but I was wondering if anyone knows any helpful guides, resources, etc.... Also, even just somewhere to start.

What I mainly want to learn about:

- setting up and acquiring SSL certificates
- handling SSL certificates
- building secure login systems
- using cookies for security purposes
- general PHP security
- SQL security

My end goal is to be able to build sites with users who's basic info I can securely store (no payment details) in an SQL database. I want to be able to create a user sign up the login and editing system. i have created something like this before but not with SSL. My question is how do you learn to do this with SSL?

could someone...
 - direct me to a guide.
 - direct me to examples.
 - point me in the right direction.

(examples would be too big to post)
like I said its quite a broad question so sorry (as someone who usually hates people who post questions like this).
Very much open to advice any help would be appreciated :)

**EDIT: My real question now is how do I learn how to use SSL and set it up after I've bought a certificate?**

Comment: It looks like it's too broad as you said (not specific question) which is not good.

Comment: you can get free SSL certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add points about which I know.

SQL security - basic principle here, never trust user input, sanitize it all. There are numerous built-in functions to do so, for example [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and real escape string: [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), for PDO, prepared statement.

using cookies for security purposes - Cookies are always a point of failure, as users can change cookies as they see fit. Best way, is to use a random string inside the cookie to identify the user later on. For example, you generate a 50 character random string, put it into a cookie, make it so it would expire over some time and store the ID into SQL, so the next time when the user connects, you can check that do you have that ID inside SQL and check who the user is. It's still unsafe, but not as unsafe as just leaving user_id's or even worse, passwords inside cookies. Using sessions is safer, but if you need to use cookies, that's the way I would do it.

building secure login systems - SSL is one key here. Another is password encryption. For PHP, use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash the password. Best way to keep passwords from not being stolen / cracked, is to also salt them. You can, for example, use AES to encrypt the password_hash itself by another random string with a key, which only you know, so you can decrypt it and verify the passwords. Also, one point here is to make sure, that you leave a failed login counter on the page, otherwise people might start flooding your site with many possible other passwords which might work. Also enforce safe passwords which are not easily figured out (test123, password, pa55w0rd etc).

setting up and acquiring SSL certificates - To get a SSL certificate which the end user can accept too without getting a message that the CA is not recognized, you most likely need to buy a SSL certificate, Google will help with that one.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer helped a lot. by the sounds of it, I might know more than I actually thought. I do make sure to sterilise user input through php and use mysql_real_escape_string etc on MySQL stuff. I also hash passwords but don't salt them so thanks. on that note I've built a user system with the help of the guide I found here: [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) I think my real question now is how do I learn how o use SSL and set it up after I've bought a certificate?

Comment: You're welcome. It's not exactly nuclear physics. You can try creating something and then try to break it yourself! :)